# Is there any way to detect greylist api usage in android project by lint?

Tags: android, interface, lint, restriction

I want to detect greylist APIs usage in an android project by lint like `veridex`. That's because of non-SDK interface restrictions in Android Q.

I tried to run lint rule "privateapis" or "restrictedapis" by `Analyze -> Run inspection by name -> "privateapis" or "restricedapis"` but the output doesn't show is not matched with the result from vertex. Veridex shows all usages with grey, black list.

If there is some setting for detecting greylist API usage by lint, please let me know that. I guess there are some Gradle version or android studio settings.

Comment: hey Zain, were you able to find some answer? I found just 1 warning in lint, while veridex shows 50+. Unable to find actual concerning line from veridex.